# Created an image component in Next.js which uses a locally hosted image, but when I run 'yarn build' I get an error?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using a Next.js template to create a personal web page to display my CS portfolio. I created a component CircularImage.js which has a circular icon of my face. When I use 'yarn dev' the image displays properly and I have no errors, but when I do 'yarn build', I get this following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/CircularImage/mememe.jpeg
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /Users/jasminewang/Documents/FALL 2023/mPortfolio-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.wasm
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14152:11)

Import trace for requested module:
./src/components/CircularImage/index.tsx
./src/components/Header/index.tsx
./src/components/Layout.tsx
./src/pages/index.tsx

> Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This is my image component's index.tsx, and I am SURE that the filepath is correct because the image shows up in 'yarn dev'...

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/dist/client/image";
import image from "./mememe.jpeg";

const CircularImage = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        borderRadius: "50%",
        overflow: "hidden",
      }}
    >
      <Image src={image} alt="A pic of me" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CircularImage;
```

Comment: Have written an answer. If my answer solves your issue, please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your `import` statement from:

```
import Image from "next/dist/client/image"
```

to:

```
import Image from "next/image"
```

I'm assuming the above issue happened because your IDE auto-imported from the incorrect location.

---

`next/dist/client/image` is an internal package used by `next`, and not something `next` recommends doing.

Refer for how Next.js recommends using the `<Image />` component: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image